# how to make an image hop with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use the animate() method in jQuery to not only give the illusion that an image bouncing but hoping across the screen, all in the same method?  (i.e. image hops like every 25 pixels across your browser screen, doing 3 hops?

Here is what I have so far...

```
//THE CSS:

.mimage {
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
top:-200px;
right:10px;
width:57px;
height:75px;
display:block;
outline:#fff;
font-size:0px;
background: url('mimage.png') top center no-repeat;
}


//THE JQUERY:

function extensions() {
/**************/
//JQ EXTENSIONS
/**************/
jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing,{   
easeInOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
if (s == undefined){ s = 1.70158;} 
if ((t/=d/2) < 1) {return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;}
return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
}
});
//*/
}

function mhop() {
/*HOPING ELF*/
$.hop = function() {
var mimage = $("#hc-elf-top");
var position = mimage.position();

if(position.top < 0) {
mimage.animate({top:'+=200px'},'slow','easeInOutBack', $.hop);
} else {
mimage.animate({top:'-=200px'},'slow','easeInOutBack', $.hop);
}
}
$.hop();
//*/        
}

//RUN THE CODE:

(function($){
extensions();
$(window).load(function(){
mhop();
})
})(jQuery);
```

As you can see, I am able to make the element bounce, but I also want to extend my scrpit to make the elf hop 25 pixels to the right. Any thoughts?

Thanks for any advice!

**MY UPDATE**

Thank you very much Abraham for the tip on using the left property under the animate method().  As a result, I was able to conclude with the following custom function to help my little elf hop across the screen.  Not only that, but you can adjust the loop value to determine how many hops you want it to take.  Feel free to use!

```
function mhop() {
  /*ELF HOPS ACROSS SCREEN*/

  var loop = 0;
  var elftop = $("#hc-elf-top");

  $.hop = function() {

  //ANIMATE THE TOP ELF TO HOP
  var elftopposition = elftop.position();
  if(elftopposition.top < 0) {
   elftop.animate({top:'+=200px',left:'+=25px'},'slow','easeInOutBack', $.hop);
  } else {
   elftop.animate({top:'-=200px',left:'+=25px'},'slow','easeInOutBack', $.hop);
  }

  //ADJUST HOW MANY HOPS THE ELF TAKES...
  if (elftopposition.top == 0) {
      loop += 1;
      if (loop == 2) {  //ADJUST HERE
        console.log('stop hopping');
        elftop.stop( true, true );
      }
  }

}

//LOOP THE FUNCTION
$.hop();
//*/        
}

 (function($){
    extensions();
    $(window).load(function(){
    mhop();
    })
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: It sure is possible. But you'll need to try something first as is the policy with SO.

Comment: thank you @j08691 for the tip!  my code is posted.  Any thoughts?

Comment: you want to increment the left position 25px each hop? like this [http://jsfiddle.net/94Mn3/](http://jsfiddle.net/94Mn3/)

Comment: I honestly didn't know it was "that" easy.  Abraham thank you so much.  If you post that as an answer, I'll give you some green.  Much appreciated!  Even though I am in the negative at the moment, I believe your solution will be a help other young jQuery developers who are looking to move their elements.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to move the .mimage you need to animate the left position where you animate the top inside the hop function like this

```
if(position.top < 0) {
    mimage.animate({top:'+=200px',left:"+=25px"},'slow','easeInOutBack', $.hop);
    console.log('the current position is: '+ position.top);
} else {
    mimage.animate({top:'-=200px',left:"+=25px"},'slow','easeInOutBack', $.hop);
}
```

you can animate more than one css property inside the animate http://jsfiddle.net/94Mn3/